# How to install Japanese font for cmatrix

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal, cmatrix

I want to use Japanese font in cmatrix, using the command

```
cmatrix -c
```

but the only thing I can see is a blank screen, so the characters aren't displayed correctly. How to install Japanese font?

Comment: Check [issue 57](https://github.com/abishekvashok/cmatrix/issues/57) on cmatrix project

Comment: @PabloBianchi the issue looks like enormous devotion of time and effort to make it work, through trial and error and I'm not sure if I would manage at all

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try out [`unimatrix`](https://github.com/will8211/unimatrix) instead of `cmatrix`.

Install with:

```
sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/will8211/unimatrix/master/unimatrix.py -o /usr/local/bin/unimatrix
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/unimatrix
```

The default setting uses half-width katakana, and looks much like the original Matrix display.

```
unimatrix
```

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: True - it's the next best solution that should probably achieve what you're after, but in a much easier way.